# Prometheus + simple time series + Python

Tags: python, time-series, prometheus, database, nosql

I'm trying to build a simple time series database in prometheus.  I'm looking at financial time series data, and need somewhere to store the data to quickly access via Python.  I'm loading the data into the time series via xml or .csvs, so this isn't some crazy "lots of data in and out at the same time" kind of project.  I'm the only user, and maybe have a couple others use it in time and just want something thats easy to load data into, and pull out of.

I was hoping for some guidance on how to do this. Few questions:

1) Is it simple to pull data from a prometheus database via python?
2) I wanted to run this all locally off my windows machine, is that doable?
3) Am I completely overengineering this? (My worry with SQL is that it would be a mess to work with, as its large time series data sets)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus is intended primarily for operational monitoring. While you may be able to get something working, Prometheus doesn't for example support bulk loading of data.

> 1) Is it simple to pull data from a prometheus database via python?

The [HTTP api](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/api/#expression-queries) should be easy to use.

> 2) I wanted to run this all locally off my windows machine, is that doable?

That should work.

> 3) Am I completely overengineering this? (My worry with SQL is that it would be a mess to work with, as its large time series data sets)

I'd more say that Prometheus is probably not the right tool for the job here. Up to say 100GB I'd consider a SQL database to be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your input brian. I guess my question with SQL is, how do I store the data?  Lets say I have 10 stocks i'm looking at. Each one has tick-by-tick data (the times don't have to be the same for each tick though, so i can't use time as my ID column).  Do I build a table for each stock? and two rows - time and price?

Comment: In that case a single table with columns for stock, time and price would work fine. Keep it simple until you hit performance issues.